# Populate MySql DB with initial data from .sql file in Spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, pom.xml

I'm using spring boot in combination with MySql DB. I have hibernate to create db tables, but I was wondering what is the easiest way to populate db with initial data such as 'users' by executing some queries from data.sql file? Also what dependencies should I add to pom.xml and properties to application-dev.yml for that matter?

Comment: You could use Spring JDBC to populate data in your application. Here you have example how to use it: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc But better solution could be using Flyway or Liquibase. How to use this tools is also described in spring documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very easy! What you need to do is create a sql file in the src/main/resources say data.sql file ; then the query you want say a insert query as :

```
 insert into admin(username,password,role)  values('admin','admin','role_admin');
```

Then add dependency :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
```

And in application.properties file add the following code;

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exampleDB
     spring.datasource.username=root
     spring.datasource.password=root
```

For more info go through this : 
[link](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2016/08/working-with-sql-databases-in-spring-boot-application.html#.WJrTz_ErIl8)

Comment: I had to name it import.sql in order to get it to work. Just throwing that out as a potential fix if anyone had problems.

Comment: @fudge, thanks so much for your comment. It helped me resolve the bug in my code by renaming data.sql to import.sql